# Cannot hide a paragraph when a checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox

I am trying to hide a paragraph when a check box is unchecked right now I can only display when it is checked.

here is my jquery:

```
$('.pharmacy').click(function(){
$('.pcsoc').show();
});
```

What can I do to hide the paragraph when it is unchecked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind to the **change** event instead:

```
$('.pharmacy').change(function(e){
  $('.pcsoc').toggle();
});
```

Or you can check if `.is(':checked')` and make your own hide/show (more bullet-proof).

```
$('.pharmacy').change(function(e){
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $('.pcsoc').show();
  else
    $('.pcsoc').hide();
});
```

Comment: Demo as well: http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/TPuB8/ -- And the `is()` version here: http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/TPuB8/1/

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('.pharmacy').click(function(){
  $('.pcsoc').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Note that using `toggle()` could possibly result in the checked/unchecked state going out of sync with the show/hide state.

Answer (score 2):

You need to test if it is checked or unchecked:

```
$('.pharmacy').click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.pcsoc').show();
  }
  else $('.pcsoc').hide();
});
```

**EDIT** It's probably better to bind to the `change()` method as suggested by Brad Christie.

Comment: I like this. Much more resilient in the likely scenario that the check_box's status cannot be predicted when the form opens.

Comment: You need to wrap `$(this)` in a jQuery object to access `.is()`

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the checkbox is checked and respond appropriately:

```
$('.pharmacy').click(function() {
    if(this.checked)
        $('.pcsoc').show();
    else
        $('.pcsoc').hide();
});
```